# LWJGL 3 - where to start?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I recently started to learn some game development and made some small games with libGDX (2D & 3D) and thought that I should know lwjgl first. But I just can't find any good tutorials or resources for lwjgl 3 (which seems to be recommended), or anything else specific to lwjgl 3.

So my question is, do you know some? Or should I use lwjgl 2 instead?

Comment: Have you seen http://www.lwjgl.org/guide ?

Comment: Yes, but it only shows me how to display a window, if I'm not mistaken. And the wiki seems to be more than incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a lot from Oscar from TheCodingUniverce, [here's his playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v56I5UWrYY&list=PL101F856590111747).
It is in LWJGL 2. I really doubt you'll find any LWJGL 3 tutorials because its still not had a 1.0 release yet, If you're new to LWJGL or Java I strongly recommend not using an untested library.

Comment: Ok thanks, I did not know that it's not released yet. Is it worth learning lwjgl 2, when version 3 is on its way?

Comment: @SebastianStieber LWJGL is just a backbone for Java to interface with OpenGL and the functions are standard and wont change, its backend stuff that you don't see that will, you should be able to take any projects you did using LWJGL 2 and simply replace 2 with 3 and not even make any code changes. So definately.

Comment: @LeeAllan LWJGL3 is a complete rewrite so it probably won't have full backwards compatibility. https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Why-a-new-version